# Query to find least fifth salaried employee

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
EMPID NAME DEPTID SALARY
---------- ------------------------------------------ --
101 surendra 201 1000
102 narendra 202 2000
103 rajesh 203 3000
104 ramesh 203 2000
105 hanumanth 202 10000
```

a) Write a Query to find least 5th (Least salary in 5th position from
least salary in the order) salaried employee?

b) Query to find the highest earning employee in each department

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  This smells like homework.

Comment: it's kind of @Tim Biegeleisaen ...but i can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a) Write a Query to find least 5th (Least salary in 5th position from least salary in the order) salaried employee?**

```
SELECT EMPID,NAME,DEPTID,SALARY
FROM
(
SELECT EMPID,NAME,DEPTID,SALARY, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY) AS RN
FROM Table1
) 
WHERE RN=5
```

**b) Query to find the highest earning employee in each department**

```
SELECT EMPID,NAME,DEPTID,SALARY
FROM
(
SELECT EMPID,NAME,DEPTID,SALARY, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPTID ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS RN
FROM Table1
)
WHERE RN=1
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63ce0/12

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume we have a table named `EmployeeSalary` which has 3 columns:

1. Id
2. Name
3. Salary

Salary might be same for multiple employee according to the following table data

```
Id  Name    Salary
----------
6   Belalo  74
1   Karim   100
5   dIPU    100
4   Satter  102
9   Kiron   120
10  Rash    120
11  Harun   130
13  Baki    130
12  Munshi  132
2   Rahim   500
7   Kaif    987
8   Sony    987
3   Belal   4000
```

Now the query will be

```
SELECT A.Salary
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Salary, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary) AS Ranks
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeSalary]
) A 
WHERE A.Ranks=5
```

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL and won't work on Oracle

Comment: It's working fine for me in SQL server

Comment: The question is about Oracle, not SQL Server